# Powerpoint 2010 has an odd resizing behavior

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I am having a display issue in PP2010 (64bit). When I fire up PP and resize the display window, the screen refreshes incorrectly. Also, although you can click around and eventually find the object you want to edit, it isn't the most enjoyable way to work.

Any ideas why this is happening?

[image]

Comment: whoa...+1 for the graphic in 1 hour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*WindowBlinds... Run!*

This is because your Desktop Window Manager or Aero is disabled, this returns it back to the XP ages...

Comment: Yep. Twas Windowblinds. Dagnabit, I like that program... :) Thanks.

Comment: I disabled WB's skinning of PP. Works just fine now and I get to keep my skins. But, this may drive me to finally not use this anymore. The number of free, quality skins has nose-dived.